# How do you create a complete html table in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have data I need to load into an html page.

I use angularjs to populate each table.  There are 8 tables total right now.

I would like to rewrite this so the table counts can be fully dynamic.

This would mean some sort of for loop for each table and then building the whole table in js.  Just a basic call to the angular controller would appear in the html page itself.

I have seen TONS of samples of how to dynamically build table rows with angularjs.  That's pretty old news.

Is it possible to build an entire table from  tags to  so I can create multiple tables nested into one big table?

Something like this?

```
<table>

for( i = 0; i < tablesCollection.length;i++ )
{
paintTable( i );
}

</table>
```

and the result would be like below (four tables nested into a two column two row master table?

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<table id=table01>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<td>
<table id=table02>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table id=table03>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<td>
<table id=table04>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) can solve your problem. Its very easy to use.

Html:

```
<div id="data-table"></div>
```

The initializing can be done dynamically, meaning that you can create the table with dynamic data (looping through json) Perhaps this solves your problem with "combining tables into one". 
A simple (static) example:

```
var table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
    {'sTitle': 'First Name', 'mData': 'first_name'},
    {'sTitle': 'Last Name', 'mData': 'last_name'},
    {'sTitle': 'Address', 'mData': 'address'},
});
```

This will create a table with columns "First Name", "Last Name" and "Address".

Updating the table with data:

```
table.row.add(data);
```

Its very easy to use, documentation is great, lots of possibilities and you can reuse a lot of the code.

Comment: Yes I am looking for something like this.  Thanks.  AngularJS doesn't have anything built in for this by the looks of it.  I have been looking and not found much so far.  I will look into JQuery data tables!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.